# Using t-test for feature selection after z-scoring data?

Tags: machine-learning, t-test, feature-selection, descriptive-statistics, z-statistic

Suppose I have a high-dimensional dataset, and a binary classification problem. I want to use the two-sample t-test for feature selection. If the data has been normalized by z-scoring (so it has zero mean and unit variance), is it still possible to use t-test?

So what is the approach I should use? Is it

- Normalize training data (then the mean is zero and variance is one for each feature)
- Select features using t-test
- Build classifier
- Normalize test data
- Test classifier

or

- Select features using t-test
- Normalize selected features
- Build classifier
- Normalize test data
- Test classifier.